# Proper implementation of an Identifying relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have an entity `Author` which has a name can write 0 .. 1 .. or many of the entity `Book`. The `Book` must be written by one `Author`, and it is not meaningful to talk of a `Book` with no `Author`.

This (I believe) would be classified as an identifying relationship. With the `EntityTypeConfiguration`, would the following be the correct way of implementing this identifying relationship?

```
public BookMapping()
{
    HasRequired(book => book.Author)
   .WithMany(author => author.Books)
   .HasForeignKey(book => book.AuthorID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not identifying relation. It is just common one-to-many relation. To make it identifying you must also map composite primary key consisting of `BookID` and `AuthorID`.

```
HasKey(book => new { book.BookID, book.AuthorID });
```